# LINQ to SQL will not generate sargable query

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ To Sql (not Entity Framework), the System.Data.Linq.DataContext library, hitting a SQL Server 2005 database and using .Net Framework 4.

The table dbo.Dogs has a column "Active" of type CHAR(1) NULL.  If I was writing straight SQL the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Dogs where Active = 'A';
```

The LINQ query is this:

```
from d in myDataContext.Dogs where d.Active == 'A' select d;
```

The SQL that gets generated from the above LINQ query converts the Active field to UNICODE.  This means I cannot use the index on the dbo.Dogs.Active column, slowing the query significantly:

```
SELECT [t0].Name, [t0].Active
FROM [dbo].[Dog] AS [t0]
WHERE UNICODE([t0].[Active]) = @p1
```

Is there anything I can do to stop Linq to Sql from inserting that UNICODE() call (and thus losing the benefit of my index on dogs.Active)?  I tried wrapping the parameters using the EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode() method, but that did no good (it inserted a CONVERT() to NVARCHAR instead of UNICODE() in the generated sql), eg:

```
...where d.Active.ToString() == EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode('A'.ToString());
```

Comment: This is my personal opinion, but it is based on my own experience - don't use Linq2SQL it produces horrible SQL Statements, and the more complex your Linq queries grow - the less optimal SQL statements are issued. Not sure about other ORMs but this one is evil.

Comment: Aye.  I should add, I'm not using Linq to Sql because I compared the different ORMs and decided Linq to Sql is best.  I am maintaining legacy code.

Comment: Although ORMs are very leaky abstractions I do not agree with cross-the-board statements to never use them. The decision depends heavily on the use case. There is clear value there and also clear disadvantages.

Comment: Well if you don't care at all about performance, I guess ORMs are ok.

Comment: Do you have an actual performance problem?  This appears to be another version of [The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

Comment: Like memory, the database is a shared resource. Each bad query, by itself, isn't a problem. But when taken as a whole you face the death of a thousand cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little hack (as it is often required with LINQ to SQL and EF). Declare the property as `NCHAR` in the dbml. I hope that will remove the need to do the `UNICODE` conversion. We are tricking L2S in a benign way with that.

Maybe you need to also insert the `EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode` call to make the right hand side a non-unicode type.

You can also try mapping the column as `varchar`.

Comment: Hacking the dbml to change "CHAR(1)" to "VARCHAR(1)" did the trick, thanks for the advice.  Of course the downside of this approach is that one can never again use the designer to update the dbml file, but for the legacy application I am working with that is not an issue.

Comment: Alternatively, using `.Equals` rather than `==` produces SQL without the `UNICODE` function call.  As to why, I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 4):

Linq is meant to make it easier to write queries and does not always generate optimal SQL. Sometimes when high performance is required it is more efficient to write raw SQL directly against the database, the Linq datacontext supports mapping of SQL result to entities just like linq. 
In your case I would suggest writing:

```
IEnumerable<Dog> results = db.ExecuteQuery<Dog>(
                           "SELECT * FROM dbo.Dogs where Active = {0}", 
                           'A');
```

Comment: Or write a stored procedure

Comment: @LoztInSpace Sure that works also, but this is less of an effort. And stored procedures are so 90ies ;-)

Comment: I wish I could mark this as the answer as well, both work, and I'll actually be implementing both in various places.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I bumped into this recently.

Instead of writing

```
from d in myDataContext.Dogs where d.Active == 'A' select d;
```

Write

```
from d in myDataContext.Dogs where d.Active.Equals('A') select d;
```

This will produce the desired SQL without having to resort to any of the "hacks" mentioned in other answers.  I can't say why for certain.

I've posted that [as a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35854481/1894317), so we'll see if we get any good answers.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much you can do to the way LINQ queries are translated into SQL statements, but you can write a stored procedure that contains your queries and call that SP as a LINQ2SQL function. This way you should get full benefit of SQL Server optimizaions

Comment: Or just write an inline SQL query, It'll map fine to DTO's just like a linq statement.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Linq2SQL supports inline queries. Is there a documentation on the feature?

Comment: @Magnus very cool, thanks! Always learn something. I think you should enter this as an answer because this suites OP needs more.