# Different SQL produced from Where(l => l.Side == 'A') vs Where(l => l.Side.Equals('A')

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I've been experimenting with queries in LinqPad.  We have a table `Lot` with a column `Side char(1)`.  When I write a linq to sql query `Lots.Where(l => l.Side == 'A')`, it produces the following SQL

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 65
-- EndRegion
SELECT ..., [t0].[Side], ...
FROM [Lot] AS [t0]
WHERE UNICODE([t0].[Side]) = @p0
```

However, using `Lots.Where(l => l.Side.Equals('A'))`, it produces

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Char(1) = 'A'
-- EndRegion
SELECT ..., [t0].[Side], ...
FROM [Lot] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Side] = @p0
```

It would appear upon (albeit naïve) inspection, that the latter would be marginally faster, as it doesn't need the call to `UNICODE`.

Using `int`, `smallint` or `varchar` columns there's no difference between the produced SQL with `==` or `.Equals`, why is `char(1)` and the corresponding C# type `char` different?

Is there any way to predict whether a given column type will produce differing SQL with the two forms of equality check?

Edit:

I have checked every type supported by MS SQL, and only `char(1)` and `nchar(1)` show this behavior.  Both are represented in LinqToSql by the `System.Char` type.  If it was a deliberate decision, then I would have expected the same behavior on `binary(1)`, which could be represented by `System.Byte` (but instead is `System.Linq.Binary` with a length of `1`.

Edit 2: In case it is relevant, I am using LINQPad to view the created SQL.  I was assuming Linqpad would use the system's LinqToSQL, but I realized today that that assumption could be flawed.

Edit 3:  I ran a quick VS project to test the system LinqToSQL, and we get the same result:

**Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var db = new DataClasses1DataContext {Log = Console.Out};
    Console.Out.WriteLine("l.Side == 'A'");
    Console.Out.WriteLine("=============");
    Console.Out.WriteLine();
    foreach (Lot ll in db.Lots.Where(l => l.Side == 'A'))
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.Out.WriteLine();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
    Console.Out.WriteLine();

    Console.Out.WriteLine("l.Side.Equals('A')");
    Console.Out.WriteLine("==================");
    Console.Out.WriteLine();
    foreach (Lot ll in db.Lots.Where(l => l.Side.Equals('A')))
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.In.Read();
}
```

**Output:**

```
l.Side == 'A'
=============

SELECT ..., [t0].[Side], ...
FROM [dbo].[Lot] AS [t0]
WHERE UNICODE([t0].[Side]) = @p0
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [65]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.6.1532.0


---------------------------------------

l.Side.Equals('A')
==================

SELECT ..., [t0].[Side], ...
FROM [dbo].[Lot] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Side] = @p0
-- @p0: Input Char (Size = 1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [A]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.6.1532.0
```

It is interesting to note that in the `== 'A'` version, the parameter is passed as an `int`, whereas in the `.Equals` version, it is passed as `char`.

[The dbml and table creation script are in this gist.](https://gist.github.com/RoadieRich/667bfb5fb61e291b4cc9e06fd3e3847d)

Comment: Can you post the DBML mapping?

Comment: @usr this was through LINQPad, for which I don't know how to retrieve the mapping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is some [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386909(v=vs.100).aspx) about this:

> Mismatches in SQL Server:
>   Fixed length character types. Transact-SQL distinguishes between Unicode and non-Unicode categories and has three distinct types in each category: fixed length nchar/char, variable length nvarchar/varchar, and larger-sized ntext/text. The fixed length character types could be mapped to the CLR System.Char type for retrieving characters, but they do not really correspond to the same type in conversions and behavior.

And the L2S source code has only one place that uses the string literal `"UNICODE"`:

[image]

It appears that a necessary precondition for the function to show up is a `SqlUnary` syntax tree node with type `Convert`:

[image]

I don't know how you managed to satisfy the `IsNumeric` condition. I think you have a type mismatch there. Is the column really mapped as `System.Char`?

The `Equals` call probably does not trigger this code path. This likely is a L2S bug.

`Equals` is translated in multiple places in the source code. Here is one of them:

[image]

It looks like this bypasses any argument conversions. It does not care what the argument is. This probably fails with a variety of queries (so it's likely a bug). I wonder what happens if you write `l.Side.Equals(1.2m)`. I guess this translates literally to SQL.

---

I have now reproduced it. Map the column to `string`. This fixes the generated SQL. The execution plan shows that an index seek is possible with the SQL that is being generated.

Comment: `l.Side.Equals(1.2m)` throws an `InvalidCastException` (Could not convert from type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Char'.) before any SQL is generated - at least, any visible sql without digging into internals.

Comment: I should probably add that I'm using LINQPad to view the created SQL, if it makes any difference.  I was assuming LINQPad would use the system L2S library, but I realized that assumption was possibly flawed.

Comment: LinqPad probably uses the unmodified binaries. You can query the mapping through the runtime metadata system of L2S. There's MSDN documentation for that. But it would be better if you created a VS project to run your tests. Right now I don't know how to proceed given that LinqPad could be using all kinds of strange mappings and invasive techniques.

Comment: See edit 3 to the question.  A VS project gives the same result.

Comment: Can you post the DBML and the SQL table create script?

Comment: Are you just interested in making this go away or do you want to understand why this is happening? The first thing to try would be to map this to a string. This should not result in any loss of performance but it might work around this L2S bug/deficiency.

Comment: I think L2S thinks that it needs to convert the column to an int because the right hand side is treated like an int although it's a char.

Comment: I have now reproduced it. Map the column to `string`. This fixes the generated SQL. The execution plan shows that an index seek is possible with the SQL that is being generated.

Comment: I'm interested in understanding why, although I have filed a bug report on the L2S forums.