# A more refined version of this LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

My conundrum is with trying to convert the following T-SQL query into a near equivalent (performance wise) LINQ to SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    j1.JOB,   
    max(CASE WHEN ISNULL(logs.statcategory, ' ') = 'PREP' THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) AS prep,  
    max(CASE WHEN ISNULL(logs.statcategory, ' ') = 'PRINT' THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) AS press,  
    max(CASE WHEN ISNULL(logs.statcategory, ' ') = 'BIND' THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) AS bind, 
    max(CASE WHEN ISNULL(logs.statcategory, ' ') = 'SHIP' THEN 'X' ELSE ' ' END) AS ship  
from 
    job j1  
left outer join 
( 
    select 
        j.job,
        l.statcategory,
        cnt=count(*)  
    from 
        job j  
    join 
        jobloc jl 
            join location l 
            on 
                l.code = jl.location and 
                l.site = jl.site 
        on j.job = jl.job  
    WHERE
        j.stat = 'O'  
    group by 
        j.job,l.statcategory  
) logs 
on 
    j1.job = logs.job  
WHERE
    j1.stat = 'O'  
group by
    j1.job
```

This query currently runs just under 0.2 seconds on MS SQL Server. The following LINQ query is what I've come up with that returns the exact same records, but runs nearly 30x slower:

```
from a0 in Jobs
join a1 in 
(
    from a0 in Jobs
    join a1 in JobLocs on a0.Content equals a1.Job
    join a2 in Locations on new {Code = a1.Location, a1.Site} equals new {a2.Code, a2.Site}
    where a0.Stat == 'O'    
    select new {a0.Content, a2.StatCategory}
) on a0.Content equals a1.Content into a1
from a2 in a1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where a0.Stat == 'O'
group a2 by a0.Content into a0
orderby a0.Key
select new 
{
    Job = a0.Key,
    Prep = (bool?)a0.Max(a1 => a1.StatCategory == "PREP" ? true : false),
    Print = (bool?)a0.Max(a1 => a1.StatCategory == "PRINT" ? true : false),
    BIND = (bool?)a0.Max(a1 => a1.StatCategory == "BIND" ? true : false),
    SHIP = (bool?)a0.Max(a1 => a1.StatCategory == "SHIP" ? true : false),
}
```

Here is the generated SQL from the LINQ query (using LINQPad):

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 79
DECLARE @p1 Int = 79
DECLARE @p2 VarChar(1000) = 'PREP'
DECLARE @p3 VarChar(1000) = 'PRINT'
DECLARE @p4 VarChar(1000) = 'BIND'
DECLARE @p5 VarChar(1000) = 'SHIP'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t4].[Job], [t4].[value] AS [Prep], [t4].[value2] AS [Print], [t4].[value3] AS [BIND], [t4].[value4] AS [SHIP]
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(
        (CASE 
            WHEN [t3].[StatCategory] = @p2 THEN 1
            WHEN NOT ([t3].[StatCategory] = @p2) THEN 0
            ELSE NULL
         END)) AS [value], MAX(
        (CASE 
            WHEN [t3].[StatCategory] = @p3 THEN 1
            WHEN NOT ([t3].[StatCategory] = @p3) THEN 0
            ELSE NULL
         END)) AS [value2], MAX(
        (CASE 
            WHEN [t3].[StatCategory] = @p4 THEN 1
            WHEN NOT ([t3].[StatCategory] = @p4) THEN 0
            ELSE NULL
         END)) AS [value3], MAX(
        (CASE 
            WHEN [t3].[StatCategory] = @p5 THEN 1
            WHEN NOT ([t3].[StatCategory] = @p5) THEN 0
            ELSE NULL
         END)) AS [value4], [t0].[Job]
    FROM [Job] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ([Job] AS [t1]
        INNER JOIN [JobLoc] AS [t2] ON [t1].[Job] = [t2].[Job]
        INNER JOIN [Location] AS [t3] ON ([t2].[Location] = [t3].[Code]) AND ([t2].[Site] = [t3].[Site])) ON ([t0].[Job] = [t1].[Job]) AND (UNICODE([t1].[Stat]) = @p0)
    WHERE UNICODE([t0].[Stat]) = @p1
    GROUP BY [t0].[Job]
    ) AS [t4]
ORDER BY [t4].[Job]
```

One thing that stands out is that the generated SQL from the LINQ query runs the aggregate for each column returned in a subquery, whereas in the original it is part of the outer SELECT. I can imagine part of the performance decrease is there.

I'm (tentatively) willing to accept that there is no better way to write this, and just use the `DataContext.ExecuteQuery()` method in the LINQ API (and just run and shape the first SQL statement directly). However, I'm trying to not include embedded SQL as much as possible in a project that I'm currently working on, so if it can be made to be near the performance of the original query, that'd be ideal. I've been hacking away at this for some time (partly as an academic exercise, and also to actually use this or similar queries like it), and this is the best I've come up with (I did not write the original query BTW--it was part of an older project that is being migrated to a newer one).

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Can you show execution plan for both?

Comment: And while your at it the definitions of the classes too ...

Comment: Is there and index on stat? I suspect that it's the UNICODE conversion.

Comment: Yes--`Stat` it is actually part of a few indices. I see what you're saying about the Unicode conversion--the server can't use the index if it has to do that. If I set the SQL data type on the `Stat` property in the `Job` class to `nchar` that may help (it is currently defined as `char`).

Comment: I just changed the generated query to not use the Unicode conversion, and it appears to have fixed the issue. I checked the execution plan and the one with the conversion gave a warning about the conversion. The second one (sans conversion) did not. The question [LINQ to SQL will not generate sargable query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979153/linq-to-sql-will-not-generate-sargable-query) and subsequent responses there also apply to this issue.

Comment: That's great then. You've got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments,

The issue is the `UNICODE` conversion that the linq-to-entities adds from some unknown reason.
the DB cannot use the index because of the (unnecessary) conversion.

You can use `.Equals` instead of `==` and it will not use `UNICODE` or change the type to `varchar(1)` in the db.